# airflow xcom value into custom operator from dynamic task id

Tags: python, jinja2, airflow, airflow-2.x

I am using the Airflow custom operator and an xcom value from a task id (generated dynamically).

how to use xcom pull to get value from a dynamic task id..

```
for id in ids :
    def dummy_push_function(**context):
    context['ti'].xcom_push(key='some_id', value='abc')
    
    dummy_operator = DummyOperator(
    task_id='Start',
    dag=main_dag
    )
    
    push_function_task = PythonOperator(
        task_id=f'{id}_push_function', --> some dynamic task id 
        provide_context=True,
        python_callable=dummy_push_function,
        op_kwargs={},
        dag=main_dag)
    
   
    push_function_task .set_upstream(dummy_operator)
    
    custom_task = CustomOperator(
            dag=main_dag,
            task_id='get_data',
            provide_context=True,
                url="http://www.google.com/{}".format("{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='{id}_push_function', key='some_id') }}")

         )

    custom_task.set_upstream(push_function_task)
```

How to add dynamic task task ids and format using the jinja syntax?

> url="http://www.google.com/{}".format("{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='{id}_push_function', key='some_id') }}")

Comment: some looping as we create tasks dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the inside of `format` function, you have `{id}` formatting variable which needs to be used in f-string or followed by `.format` but it is neither f-string nor having `.format` function followed by the string.

`"{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='{id}_push_function', key='some_id') }}"` is not f-string, therefore, the `{id}` is printed as literal "{id}".

However, having f-string within `format` is a little complex. I think it is easier to use 1 f-string by escaping the brackets.

To escape "{", you need an extra "{", so to escape jinja's brackets "{{", you need "{{{{".

```py
url=f"http://www.google.com/{{{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='{id}_push_function', key='some_id') }}}}"
```

Now, f-string will be evaluated first, then passed to `CustomOperator` where I am assuming the `url` is `templated_fields` which will transform the passed string with jinja.

```py
id = 1
f"http://www.google.com/{{{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='{id}_push_function', key='some_id') }}}}"

>> # after f-string evaluated
"http://www.google.com/{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='1_push_function', key='some_id') }}"
```